# rjags error Error in mat[, "deviance"] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, jags, rjags

I'm running a model in R using the package 'jagsUI' and the model begins to run  for a little bit, but then I get the message

"Error in mat[, "deviance"] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In order.params(samples, parameters.to.save, DIC, verbose = verbose) :
JAGS did not monitor deviance."

I've never come across this error before I thought it might be an issue with the DIC module of JAGS so I made sure to load the module when running the model. Any suggestions on what might be causing this?

Here is my code:

```
#write out model
writeLines("

       model {                                  #Open overall model bracket

       ############################################################
       #Priors
       ############################################################

       omega ~ dunif(0,1)

       alpha.lam~dnorm(0,0.1)

      Beta_FEDR[1] <- 0
      Beta_FEDR[2]~dnorm(0,0.1)
      Beta_FEDR[3]~dnorm(0,0.1)
      Beta_FEDR[4]~dnorm(0,0.1)
      Beta_FEDR[5]~dnorm(0,0.1)
      Beta_FEDR[6]~dnorm(0,0.1)
      Beta_FEDR[7]~dnorm(0,0.1)


       # i obs random effect
       for (i in 1:N) {
       eps[i]~dnorm(0,tau.disp)#I(-20,20)  #random observation effect
       }

       #hyperprior on random observation effects precision
       tau.disp ~ dgamma(0.1,0.001)


       ############################################################
       #Likelihood specification
       ############################################################

       for (i in 1:N){                                          # Open i likelihood bracket; corresponds to obs
       #n observations

       w[i] ~ dbern(omega)
       NREKN[i] ~ dpois(eff.lambda[i]) 
       eff.lambda[i] <- w[i]*lambda[i]

       log(lambda[i]) <- alpha.lam + Beta_FEDR[FEDR[i]] +eps[i]

       # Fit assessments

       residual[i] <- NREKN[i] - eff.lambda[i]
       predicted[i] <- eff.lambda[i]
       sq[i] <- pow(residual[i],2)


       # Generate replicate datasets
       NREKN.new[i] ~ dpois(eff.lambda[i])
       sq.new[i] <- pow(NREKN.new[i]-predicted[i],2)


       } # close i likelihood bracket

       ############################################################
       #Derived quantities
       ############################################################
       # Add up discrepancy measures
       fit <- sum(sq[])
       fit.new <- sum(sq.new[])
       test <- step(fit.new-fit)
       bpvalue <- mean(test)
       } #close model

       ", con = here("Shorebird_aquaculture_project","REKN_Models", 
      "ZIP_DistOnlyModel.txt"))

#Identify filepath of model file;
modfile <- here("Shorebird_aquaculture_project","REKN_Models", 
"ZIP_DistOnlyModel.txt")

sink(file=here("Shorebird_aquaculture_project","OutputFiles","REKN","outputDistOnlyModel.txt"))

 #create JAGS model object 'out' using the jags function of package jagsUI             

out <- jags(data = data,
 parameters.to.save = params,
 inits = initsFunction,
 model.file = modfile,
 modules=c('glm','dic'),
 n.chains = 2,
 n.adapt = 100,
 n.iter = 30000,
 n.burnin = 10000,
 n.thin = 2,
 parallel=TRUE,
 seed=as.integer(Sys.time()),
 n.cores=2)

sink()
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't definitively say (so maybe this should be a comment, not an answer), but I just encountered this exact error message and was able to resolve it.

Turns out I had forgotten to include the response variable in my input data!

Only when I ran with `parallel=F` did I get the error message `There are no observed stochastic nodes`.  My guess is this message is suppressed when running in parallel, and that the error we observed gets tripped before the "missing data" error.

I realize this comes 6 months late, but maybe it's useful to someone down the line.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Tyers, the problem was the dependent variable specification in the model. I have "NREKN" as the dependent variable, but in the data file it was coded as "REKN", such a lame mistake on my part

Comment: @Matt Tyers Thanks!! I had the error message "Failed to set trace monitor for deviance There are no observed stochastic nodes" and the reason was that I also forgot to include my response variable in my input data!